# Since everything in an object in Python, which is the top most object?

Tags: python, java

In Python, it is said that everything is an object. Could someone please help me which is the top most object.

Do we have any such thing Java? Java does have a parent class called "Object" from which all other classes are inheriting. Not everything is an object in Java.

Is the OO principle w.r.t the above, different between Python and Java?

Comment: Are you sure you would like to know about the top-most *object*? Python uses class-based OOP, not [prototype-based OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Prototype-based_programming&oldid=1138055586).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "top most"? Please also make sure you are clear about the distinction between objects and classes.

Comment: "which is the top most object." you mean the *top most type or class*? In Java, it is `Object`, in Python, it is `object`

Answer (score 3):

The root of the object hierarchy is 'object':

```
 class foo:
    pass
```

and

```
 class foo(object):
     pass
```

mean the same thing in Python3.

Empirical evidence:

```
>>> class C:
...  pass
...
>>> C.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
>>>
```

Documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object

Comment: I think this is correct, but could you add a reference to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and explain where/how this is stated there?

Comment: If I am not wrong, what you have explained is class hierarchy. All class in Python inherits from Object class (just like Java). Actually I am interested in knowing the top most object in Python. Thanks for taking time and answering!

Comment: @LoverofStructure - oddly enough, I can't find any such statement in the doc.  Can you?  Feel free to edit my answer if you can.

Comment: I'm not aware of a top-most object as distinct from a top-most class.

Comment: Seems to be [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object), though the other answerer seems to have found the right place in the documentation already.

Comment: @user3103957 "top most object" doesn't make any sense. That is not a standard term, so you are going to have to explain what you mean.

Comment: Sure, we come across this statement "Everything is an object in Python." This is ubiquitous across the internet. So I understand there must be a top most object. This concept is not present in Java. It has a clean hierarchy: Object -> other classes.

Comment: @user3103957 no, "everything is an object" **absolutly does not imply that there is a "top most object"** You sound fundamentally confused, because in Python, there is a clean hierarchy as well, `object -> <everything else>`. "everything is an object" pretty much means there are no "primitive types" like in Java, vs "object/reference types". There is no such distinction in Python. it doesn't imply anything about the class heirarchy (which python and java are the same in that respect that they have a top-level type named "object")

Comment: @user3103957 note, you haven't even really *defined* what you mean by "top most object".

Comment: If everything is an `object` then presumably the top-most `object` must be the `object` object?

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the topmost object is `object`.

> It is the base class for all other classes in Python. ([reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object))

The concept of `object` and `class` are actually both `objects`, as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes):

> Creating a new class creates a new type of object, allowing new
> instances of that type to be made.

All objects in Python, including integers, strings, and functions, inherit from `object`.

---

In Java, the topmost object is `Object`.

> Class `Object` is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has `Object` as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class. ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html))

However, unlike Python, primitive types like `int` and `boolean` are not objects in Java and do not inherit from `Object`.

---

The object-oriented principles of Python and Java are similar in many ways, as both languages are object-oriented and share many concepts, such as encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism. They also have differences:

For example, Python supports multiple inheritance, where a subclass can inherit from multiple base classes:

> the class inheritance mechanism allows multiple base classes ([reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes))

while Java only supports single inheritance, where a subclass can inherit from only one base class:

> Each class except Object is an extension of (that is, a subclass of) a single existing class and may implement interfaces. ([reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4))

And there are many more different implementations of them.

I suggest you do more reading on [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/) and [Python](https://www.python.org/doc/) offical documents to understand these concepts. The documents are explained with examples, which can better answer your question.

Comment: I think you're making the same mistake I made, answering for a top-level class instead of a top-level object.  The difference is this: if we define a class C, and then create two instances of C, call them c1 and c2, then both c1 and c2 have an instance of 'object' as their 'parent', but it's notionally a different instance between the two.  And I'm not happy with saying *those* instances of 'object' inherit from the 'object' class.

Comment: @ArfurNarf I suspect OP is meaning to ask about the top-most class in the class hierarchy, despite their wording -- see my comment above.

Comment: @ArfurNarf I don't think there is concept difference between a `object` and a `class` in Python. As you know, everything in Python is `object`, so a class is also a `object`. Quoted from the official document: "Creating a new class creates a new type of object, allowing new instances of that type to be made."  [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Sure, but while objects-that-are-classes form a rooted directed acyclic graph (navigable via the \__bases__ attribute), at best objects-that-are-not-classes form a disconnected set of DAGs.

Comment: @ArfurNarf  objects that are not classes do not have a well-defined hierarchy. While they may have attributes and methods, they are not inherently related to other objects in any way. Therefore, they do not form a DAG in the same way that classes do. Instead, they form disconnected sets of DAGs (or sometimes just disconnected graphs) depending on how they are related to other objects. For example, a list object may be related to other list objects through the use of the append method or through slicing, but it is not related to a string object or a dictionary object.

Comment: @ArfurNarf I believe the one who is making a mistake is the OP. There is no standard notion of a "top object". He is obviously talking about `object` given his reference to Java's `Object`